# illegal characters at line 1 and col 1 in xml response in jmeter

Tags: jmeter

I am trying to validate the xml response from an REST API using JMETER. I am using xml schema assertion to validate the response using xsd.

I am getting the following error on XML Schema Assertion

```
Assertion error: true
Assertion failure: false
Assertion failure message: fatal: line=1 col=1 Content is not allowed in prolog.
```

When i see the response that i have received i see there are some illegal characters that is added at the beginning of the response xml.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MGpZm.jpg)

I have tried to modify jmeter.properties file and changed the following values

```
jmeter.save.saveservice.output_format=xml
jmeter.save.saveservice.data_type=true
jmeter.save.saveservice.label=true
jmeter.save.saveservice.response_code=true
jmeter.save.saveservice.successful=true
jmeter.save.saveservice.thread_name=true
```

Please help me in understanding how to remove the illegal characters in the response and allow the xsd validation to pass through.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

These characters indicate [Byte Order Mark](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Byte_order_mark) so you can use [BOMInputStream](https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-io/javadocs/api-2.6/org/apache/commons/io/input/BOMInputStream.html) from the [JSR223 PostProcessor](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#JSR223_PostProcessor) in order to remove them from the response and replace the response data with "sanitized" XML.

1. Add JSR223 PostProcessor as a child of the [HTTP Request](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#HTTP_Request) sampler where you want to remove this BOM
2. Put the following code into "Script" area:

   ```
   def is = new ByteArrayInputStream(prev.getResponseData())
   def bOMInputStream = new org.apache.commons.io.input.BOMInputStream(is)
   def bom = bOMInputStream.getBOM()
   def charsetName = bom == null ? 'UTF-8' : bom.getCharsetName()
   def reader = new InputStreamReader(new BufferedInputStream(bOMInputStream), charsetName)
   prev.setResponseData(org.apache.commons.io.IOUtils.toByteArray(reader, 'UTF-8'))
   ```
3. That's it, your assertion shouldn't be failing anymore.

More information on Groovy scripting in JMeter: [Apache Groovy - Why and How You Should Use It](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/groovy-new-black)